What is the difference between I do what I want,or I do what I want to do?
What's the difference between doin what you want&doing what you want to do?

Please clarify the problem.

Compare I eat what I want (to eat).   You might want a Lamborghini, but you can't eat it. The only difference is that the infinitival complement (to eat, to do) is explicitly stated. There's no practical difference in meaning.

I do what I want, I do what I want to, I do what I want to do - no difference.

They have the same meaning. In general in English, sentences with more words are often perceived as more formal than sentences with fewer words. So, "I do what I want to do" might be a little bit more formal than "I do what I want." But that is a very small change.

They mean the same thing. At least, they sound like they mean the same thing to me. If you're thinking there's some difference, please explain.
